# Open Modal from another page Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I working on laravel project and I have many modals that I will using in my project so I decided to put  modals code in another folder .
my view code is

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data- 
 target="#AddUserMoodal"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

when I pressing on this button  I want to open AddModal which is in modals folder 
this is code of /modals/addmodal.blade.php

```
 <div id="addModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title_add" autofocus>
                            <small>Min: 2, Max: 32, only text</small>
                            <p class="errorTitle text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="content">Content:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="content_add" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
                            <small>Min: 2, Max: 128, only text</small>
                            <p class="errorContent text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'></span> Add
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but I don't know how to do that .what is the route will be for it

Comment: If your code/component is in folder `/resources/views/modals/addmodal.blade.php` you can access it by `@include('modals.addmodal')` or `@component('modals.addmodal')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you are in home page : `home.blade.php` , use `include`

```
<body>

    @include('models/addmodal')

</body>
```

If your modal is dynamic , and you want to pass data to modal :

```
<body>

   @include('models/addmodal',['title'=>$title,'data'=>$data])

</body>
```

and in your addmodal

```
<div id="addModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              {{$title}}
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's `modals/`, not `models/`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [@include directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views).

**Side note:**

Just for reference, back in the old of Laravel you could solve it like this:

```
// routes.php (which is web.php now)
Route::get('view-component/{name}', function ($name) {
    return view($name);
});

// In your view
{{ route('view-component/user-form') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include your blade file with

`@include('path.to.your.blade')`

You can have your HTML structure in parts and just include them as above.

Check Laravel documentation for blade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views